# Adjust TabBar Items to fill entire screen width but have different proportions?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tabbar

I'm trying to get into Flutter development, and I've been following along some tutorials that matched an app I'm trying to make. Now, I'm mainly a web developer, so I thought this would be as easy a task as it is with CSS, but for some reason a very simple task I'm trying to achieve has proven to be more of a challenge than I hoped to.

I have an AppBar item, appended with a TabBar item, with two text items in it, them being "Chats" and "Me". As the names imply, the Chats tab will hold the chat window, and the Me tab will hold quick options relative to the current user, and as such, I'd like for the Chats window to take precedent, making it also a bigger item. I've tried setting the TabBar to Scrollable, but all it does is set the tab items to their content's width and center it. I can then adjust their width, but the size loses it's responsiveness.

Is there any way to make an item occupy, say, 90% of the TabBar and another 10%?
Below is a few snippets to illustrate what I'm talking about. Top one is what I currently have working, bottom one is my desired proportions.

TabBar as I currently have it working

[image]

TabBar as I wish for it to be

[image]

And if the window's width changes, the width of the items adjusts to keep the proportions intact

[image]

And here is the code I have in Flutter

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    title: const Text("AppName"),
    elevation: 0.7,
    bottom: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        tabs: [
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0),
              child: Tab(text: "Chats")),
          Container(child: Tab(text: "Me")),
        ]),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Instead html/CSS it would be easy if you include an image that are you trying to archive

Comment: @YeasinSheikh You're right, that's what I thought of doing initially but I'm currently in Linux and GIMP and I are sworn enemies, so I chose to do it the way that was easiest to me. Anyways changed the html/css code to images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set the attribute isScrollable to true, and set labelPadding in horizontal axis to 0:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        title: const Text("AppName"),
        elevation: 0.7,
        bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Container(
                  width: width * 0.85,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  // padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80.0),
                  child: const Tab(text: "Chats")),
              Container(
                  width: width * 0.15,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: const Tab(text: "Me")),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

to change the width upon clicking the bar, define a bool with initialized value of true, and wrap both container with (InkWell) widget, ontTap will change the value of bool. and you can use that bool to change the width of containers:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
     setState(() {
        b = true;
     });
  },
  child: Container(
     width: b? width * 0.85: width * 0.15,
     color: Colors.orange,
     child: const Tab(text: "Chats")),
  ),
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
     setState(() {
        b = false;
     });
  },
  child: Container(
     width: b? width * 0.15: width * 0.85,
     color: Colors.red,
     child: const Tab(text: "Me")),
),
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using `PreferredSize` bottom. For animation you can choose other widget too, for now you can test it with AnimatedSize instead of AnimatedContainer because it will overlap some color transaction,

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("AppName"),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize:
                Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, kToolbarHeight),
            child: Container(
                child: Row(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    _tabController.animateTo(0);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: AnimatedSize(
                    key: const ValueKey("animatedTan 0"),
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 333),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: kToolbarHeight,
                      color: _tabController.index == 0
                          ? Colors.purple
                          : Colors.transparent,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                          (_tabController.index == 0 ? .9 : .1),
                      child: Text("Chats"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    _tabController.animateTo(1);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: AnimatedSize(
                      key: const ValueKey("animatedTan 1"),
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 333),
                      child: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          height: kToolbarHeight,
                          color: _tabController.index == 1
                              ? Colors.purple
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                              (_tabController.index == 1 ? .9 : .1),
                          child: Text("Me"))),
                )
              ],
            )),
          ),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Text(" ${_tabController.index}");
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, that's very close to what I want, thank you! Just a few more questions about adjustments to this, I'd like it to stay the same size after clicking on it (so both the "Chats" and "Me" tab stay the same size, independently of being clicked). What part of this code you sent is responsible for the resizing, so I can disable it? Also how do I change the text color to white? So far I was able to change the active/inactive background color, but not the text's color itself. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Width of the container, like `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (_tabController.index == 0 ? .9 : .1),` You can find more about [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)